# Convert Strings to DateTime?

Tags: c#, datetime

The datatype I need is `DataTime?`
The sample string values I have are like `11/28/2014 1:40:42 AM`
What format should I use to convert them to `DateTime?` 
I found the `DateTime.ParseExact` method but still not sure what to enter as the format based on the shape of the input that I have.

Comment: To use parse exact, see the MSDN for formatting tips: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: It looks like "G" from the standard list: 6/15/2009 1:45:30 PM.  If you do not expect this to change, you may want to use ParseExact instead of Parse.

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact("11/28/2014 1:40:42 AM", "G",  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the invariant culture to parse this format:

```
DateTime? result = DateTime.Parse("11/28/2014 1:40:42 AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The type of the `result` variable will be `DateTime?` (which is the same as `Nullable<DateTime>`). Please make sure that you really need a nullable type here, because the result of `DateTime.Parse` will always be a `DateTime` value and never `null`.

If you want to catch cases where the parsing fails, you can go for this:

```
DateTime result;
if (!DateTime.TryParse("11/28/2014 1:40:42 AM",
                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                        DateTimeStyles.None,
                        out result))
{
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: For what reason did you declare as `var` and then cast? Why not just declare as `DateTime?`?

Comment: "var" means for the compiler to use whatever type the right hand side of the assignment is. I casted to Nullable<DateTime> (DateTime?) because OP asked for it. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, is there also a way to catch bad formats for more safety? for example do I need to check for result being null or do I need to wrap it in a try-catch?  and yep, the schema is Nullable DateTime

Comment: @Frank I know what `var` does. That wasn't the point of my question. If you declared as `DateTime?` instead of `var` you wouldn't even need to cast, and the type is immediately apparent.

Comment: rshepp, you're right. Resharper put the var there and I didn't simplify. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code.

```
try
{
   DateTime Value = DateTime.Parse("11/28/2014 1:40:42 AM", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
   //throw exception
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See [`DateTime.Parse(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40(v=vs.110).aspx), which uses the default format provider. Generally you want to go with the default, because of the way cultural converters change the formatting (and they change `DateTime` a LOT).

Comment: OP asks to parse a specific format: 11/28/2014 1:40:42 AM